# Replace submatrix of NA entries with another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with property such that when you delete the non `NA` entries in each row, you are left with a smaller rectangular matrix. For example:

```
is_na_mat <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                         FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), .Dim = c(4L, 3L))
tmp_b <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
tmp_b[!is_na_mat] <- 0
```

which is the matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA    0
[2,]    0   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    0
[4,]   NA    0   NA
```

Deleting the non-`NA` entries of `tmp_b` leaves you with a 4x2 submatrix matrix of `NA`'s.

I wish to replace this submatrix with `tmp_a`, the matrix:

```
tmp_a <- cbind(1:4,-(1:4))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   -1
[2,]    2   -2
[3,]    3   -3
[4,]    4   -4
```

so that the resultant matrix is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   -1    0
[2,]    0    2   -2
[3,]    3   -3    0
[4,]    4    0   -4
```

I have `tmp_b[is_na_mat] <- tmp_a` but this produces:

```
> tmp_b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    0
[2,]    0   -1   -3
[3,]    2   -2    0
[4,]    3    0   -4
```

which is wrong, as the indexing into `tmp_b` causes the `NA` entries to be replaced in columnwise order.

Comment: When in doubt transpose some more.. `tb = t(tmp_b)  ;
tb[t(is_na_mat)] <- t(tmp_a) ; t(tb)`

Comment: and   `idx = which(is.na(tmp_b), arr.ind=TRUE) ; idx = idx[order(idx[,1]), ] ; tmp_b[idx] <- t(tmp_a)`

Comment: @user20650 - I like comment #2 - you should make it an answer.

Comment: thanks for the comments, they are all very useful. The commands are still clunky and very hard to get your head around. I agree with @thelatemail, they should be in an answer!

Comment: And if I was code-golfing, you could do `t(replace(t(tmp_b), is.na(t(tmp_b)), t(tmp_a)))`